# How to make iphone angled back button using CSS or SVG with semantic html mobile website (iPhone, Android)?

Tags: android, html, mobile, css, svg

How to make iPhone back button in CSS3?

Using only `<a href="#">Back</a>` and the button should look similar in iphone safari and **Android browser.**

[image]

In the given answer The button is really made by without image. But the html code is not semantic

```
<a href="#">
      <div class="body">
        <div>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <p>Back</p><p>
      </p></div>
      </a>
```

Is there any other better semantic way to make this button with less complicated code?

like with this code

```
<a href="#">
 <span>Back</span>
</a>
```

I'm only considering CSS3 supported browser.

---

**Edit: 29 September 2011**

**Is it possible to make button like this using SVG?**

Comment: Yes it's possible to make that in SVG.

Answer (score 3):

I've found out this implementation, which is much better semantics and mostly only plays with the CSS to achieve best result: [here](http://dream-world.us/2011/11/30/the-best-pure-css3-ios-style-arrow-back-button/)

Answer (score 2):

Done a while ago by Jeff Batterton, here you go: http://lab.jeffbatterton.com/iphone-back-button/ :-)

Comment: In this link he is using this much html to make the button `<div class="body">
        <div>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <p>Back</p><p>
      </p></div>`

Comment: Its a good idea, and *almost* works but you can see the join between the 2 divs (that rotated div and the rest of the button).